# how to send data to AsyncTask from Activity?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

i am developing one application in that i have to send data to server .i got exception while get user details nullpointer exception please tell me where i made mistake

myActivity code

```
userDetails = new DetailsDTO();

userName = userNameEdit.getText().toString().trim();
password = passwordEdit.getText().toString().trim();
confirmPwd = confirmPasswordEdit.getText().toString();
mobileNo = mobileNoEdit.getText().toString();

userDetails.setUserName(userName);
userDetails.setPassword(password);
userDetails.setConfirmPwd(confirmPwd);
userDetails.setMobileNumber(mobileNo);

(new UserDetailsAsync(mContext)).execute();
```

My AsyncTask  code :

```
    @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            httpClient  = new DefaultHttpClient();
            httpPost = new HttpPost(TrafficConstants.USER_REG_URL);


            Log.e("userName", details.getUserName());
            Log.e("pass", details.getPassword());
            Log.e("MOb",details.getMobileNumber());

            try{
            arrayList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
            arrayList.add(new 
                    BasicNameValuePair("usr",details.getUserName()));
            arrayList.add(new 
                   BasicNameValuePair("pass",details.getPassword()));
            arrayList.add(new 
                   BasicNameValuePair("mob",details.getMobileNumber()));
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(arrayList));
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
```

LogCat Error

```
 02-20 12:16:37.535: E/AndroidRuntime(2605): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
02-20 12:16:37.535: E/AndroidRuntime(2605):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
02-20 12:16:37.535: E/AndroidRuntime(2605):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
02-20 12:16:37.535: E/AndroidRuntime(2605):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
02-20 12:16:37.535: E/AndroidRuntime(2605):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
02-20 12:16:37.535: E/AndroidRuntime(2605):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
02-20 12:16:37.535: E/AndroidRuntime(2605):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
02-20 12:16:37.535: E/AndroidRuntime(2605):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
02-20 12:16:37.535: E/AndroidRuntime(2605):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
02-20 12:16:37.535: E/AndroidRuntime(2605): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
02-20 12:16:37.535: E/AndroidRuntime(2605):     at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
02-20 12:16:37.535: E/AndroidRuntime(2605):     at android.util.Log.e(Log.java:231)
02-20 12:16:37.535: E/AndroidRuntime(2605):     at com.technowellServices.locationfind.UserRegistratrionActivity$UserDetailsAsync.doInBackground(UserRegistratrionActivity.java:150)
02-20 12:16:37.535: E/AndroidRuntime(2605):     at com.technowellServices.locationfind.UserRegistratrionActivity$UserDetailsAsync.doInBackground(UserRegistratrionActivity.java:1)
02-20 12:16:37.535: E/AndroidRuntime(2605):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
```

Comment: Post your error log, that is logcat

Comment: You have set data to userDetails object and getting from details object?? use userDetails  in place of details

Comment: i added please see under my code

Comment: i wrote both are in separate classes

Comment: @Durga    `Log.e("userName", details.getUserName())``details` is probably null. where is it initialized?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While declaring the AsyncTask in your class , declare it as follow :

```
class TestAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Context, Void, Void>{

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Context... params) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                             Context context = params[0];                                 

                return null;
            }

        }
```

The first parameter for the accepts the parameter you want to pass to the Asynctask created by you.

Also, call it as :

```
new TestAsyncTask().execute(MyActivity.this);
```

Answer (score 3):

Better try pass your Object to AsyncTask doInBackground:

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(DetailsDTO... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        httpClient  = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httpPost = new HttpPost(TrafficConstants.USER_REG_URL);

        DetailsDTO userDetails = params[0];

        Log.e("userName", userDetails.getUserName());
        Log.e("pass", userDetails.getPassword());
        Log.e("MOb",userDetails.getMobileNumber());

        try{
        arrayList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
        arrayList.add(new 
                BasicNameValuePair("usr",userDetails.getUserName()));
        arrayList.add(new 
               BasicNameValuePair("pass",userDetails.getPassword()));
        arrayList.add(new 
               BasicNameValuePair("mob",userDetails.getMobileNumber()));
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(arrayList));
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Then in your `Activity` class:

```
new UserDetailsAsync().execute(userDetails);
```

If this won't help, write exactly `150 line` of your activity class, which crashes your app with NPE.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
new UserDetailsAsync(userName,password,confirmPwd,mobileNo,mContext)).execute();
```

In your **AsyncTask** add constructor

```
        String userName,password,confirmPwd,mobileNo;
        Context context;
        //  constructor
        public UserDetailsAsync(String userName,String password,String confirmPwd,String mobileNo, Context context) {
            this.userName = userName;
            this.password = password;
            this.confirmPwd = confirmPwd;
            this.mobileNo = mobileNo;
            this.context = context;
        }
```

Or

use your **userDetails** in your activity as `public static userDetails`

and in your **AsyncTask**

```
        Log.e("userName", YourActivity.userDetails.getUserName());
        Log.e("pass", YourActivity.userDetails.getPassword());
        Log.e("MOb", YourActivity.userDetails.getMobileNumber());
```

Comment: @Durga no it's not. Your initilize as `details = new DetailsDTO();` so it is initilize as new.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the instance of your `userDetails = new DetailsDTO();` inside the AsyncTask and changing `details.getUserName()`  to `userDetails .getUserName()`

Answer (score 0):

I think your `doinbackground` method return null. So its may cause error in `onpostexecute`